# Kivy buildozer: specify precise python3 version

Tags: kivy, buildozer

Is there a way to specify the precise version of python3 that is bundled to apk? How can I figure out what the latest supported version?
When I write `requirements = python3` in the `buildozer.spec` file, I don't
know what exactly python 3 version is going to be bundled. Of course, I can check it from my app by writing something like:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

But that definitely not the best option.

Answer (score 1):

try the following params in buildozer.spec file

```
requirements = python3==3.11.1, hostpython3==3.11.1, kivy, sqlite3, requests, kivymd, pydantic
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Probably can reach this with

```
requirements = python3=3.7
```

Comment: It has some effect, but when I try to specify python3==3.8.1, buildozer finishes with error that some library -lptyhon3... missing

Comment: try python 3.7 .. this is supported for sure

Comment: Still no luck. When I specify requirements = python3==3.7.2, it gives no errors or warnings, but print(sys.version) still gives 3.7.1. At least I figured out that maximum supported python version for buildozer 1.0.1-dev0 is 3.7.1

Comment: You can't just write arbitrary python versions in there and expect it to work. You *can* write versions and expect buildozer to download and attempt to use them, it just might fail in a range of ways. The best option is to just stick with the default (3.7.1) or maybe try something else from the 3.7 family.

Comment: Also the reason you got 3.7.1 after writing 3.7.2 is buildozer reused the cached build, you have to make sure to clean everything if you want to attempt a rebuild.

Comment: Also, python3.8 will be supported soon, we have it working but the changes aren't yet merged or released.

Comment: @inclement Thanks for the clarification, that's helpful. Indeed, using the default version whenever possible can alleviate the development process very much.

Comment: It'd also be nice if buildozer documentation highlights supported versions of Python and Android SDK|NDK in the documentation, on the title page if possible

Comment: For the Android SDK and NDK, the supported versions vary by python-for-android version. Since the point of buildozer is to hide these details in the first place and just fetch the correct things, it's deliberate that it doesn't give much detail. The Python version would be more useful and I'll maybe look into it - it's becoming more important than it used to be as we support various python3 versions with different features.

Answer (score 0):

For example (in the buildozer.spec file):

```
requirements = python3==3.6.9, hostpython3==3.6.9, kivy
```

sets the 'pythons' to use as 3.6.9

On changing the buildozer.spec file you'll have to delete the *bin/* and *.buildozer/* folder so that buildozer installs the correct versions of python.